# Is vars() same as __dict__?

Tags: python

I read that `vars()` is a built-in that returns the `__dict__` attribute of class, module or object. But when I checked for `vars(Person) is Person.__dict__`, it returned `False`(`Person` is the name of class).

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

vars(Person) is Person.__dict__  # False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes create a new mappingproxy on every `__dict__` access. You would see the exact same results from `Person.__dict__ is Person.__dict__`.

Comment: @AnunadSingh If this answered your question, you can accept it by hitting on the check mark.